# SSH Tunnel for PostgreSQL - Connection Refused

Tags: postgresql, ssh

I am, for the first time, attempting to set up an application on a remote/cloud VPS (I am using Digital Ocean if it matters). I am attempting to create an SSH tunnel from my client to the remote database. As this is not something I have attempted before, I referenced [this](https://linuxaria.com/howto/online-budget-with-gnucash-mysql-ssh), [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ssh-tunnels.html), and [this](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205408088-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel).

After looking over the articles, I ran the following on my client/local machine:

```
 ssh -L 5433:localhost:5432 user@REMOTE_IP
```

then I tried to connect:

```
 psql -h localhost -p 5433 postgres;
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

To my knowledge, my pg_hba.conf (on the remote server) is the default:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I changed "listen_addresses" in postgresql.conf to *

```
    # - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
```

I also tried substituting 127.0.0.1 forlocalhost with no success.

Any advice would be appreciated; SSH tunnels and the like are not something I am familiar with.

Thanks.
EDIT:

Per @drdaeman excellent advice, I ran the following:

sudo ssh -N -vvv -L 5433:localhost:5432 user@host

The last few debug lines are as follows:

```
    debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5433.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

Output from `sudo netstat -ltpn | grep 5432`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5835/postgres
```

It stops there, unresponsive to any commands.

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: Restart the server?

Comment: Thanks sibert. I tried restarting both PostgreSQL and the server itself but no change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, everything looks OK to me - don't see where the problem is, but the commands you're running and your configuration looks correct. Here are the general steps you can take to diagnose the issue:

First, check if your PostgreSQL server is actually listening. On your server, run this:

```
$ sudo netstat -ltpn | grep 5432
```

(Or you can use `ss -ltpn` from iproute2 instead of older `netstat`)

If you don't see anything, it means no process is listening on tcp/5432. You can try to see if PostgreSQL is listening anywhere at all:

```
$ sudo netstat -lpn | grep postgre
```

If it doesn't - check whenever your server is actually running (depends on the OS and distribution, but check `ps aux` output first) and check your server logs (probably in `/var/log`) if you see any problems there.

Then, make sure you don't accidentally run `psql` on your server (when you SSH, it also opens the shell session unless you specify the `-N` flag). You need to run it on your local machine ;)

Then, you may also consider adding `-v` (or even `-vvv`) to your `ssh` command - it'll spew a lot of useful debug information, e.g. a normal operation looks like this:

```
debug1: Connection to port 5433 forwarding to localhost port 5432 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 5433 for localhost port 5432, connect from ::1 port 60039 to ::1 port 5433, nchannels 4
```

If you see something like `channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused` instead, this means PostgreSQL had refused the connection - and you need to check its logs for the reasoning - possibly, after enabling `log_connections` and `log_disconnections` in the config (don't forget to reload the configuration).

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to reconfigure `listen_addresses` so you don't end up with your PostgreSQL instance exposed to the world. You don't need it listening on `0.0.0.0` and/or `[::]`, if you use SSH tunneling. It only has to listen on `127.0.0.1` and/or `::1`.

Comment: Thanks much. Excellent advice. I have added the debug output above.

Comment: @KellyMarchewa Two questions to diagnose this further: 1) have you checked if the server is running listening correctly? And 2) the ssh output you had shown is normal (and, yes, it'll get stuck like this - you can terminate it with ctrl+c when you don't need it anymore) but does anything happen to the `ssh` output when you run `psql`? It should say e.g. `debug1: Connection to port 5433 forwarding to localhost port 5432 requested.` when you do. Port forwarded connections are only established when they're requested, not when you run `ssh` and connect.

Comment: Ok, your Postgres is listening, `ssh -vvv -N -L 5433:127.0.0.1:5432 your.server.example.org` should work. You can try `telnet localhost 5433` instead of `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 postgres` just to see if it connects. Watch out for ssh output - it must say something if there are any connection attempts. If it doesn't then there is no connection (or something is really broken). Seeing as you have marked answer as accepted, I hope you have figured the exact cause. I suspect it's something about `psql` invocation, or IPv4/IPv6 mix issue (e.g. ssh trying to connect to ::1 instead of 127.0.0.1).